# Calculating the variance and standard deviation of a Laplace distribution

Tags: probability

In my statistics course I was given the following distribution function:

$f_{\mathbb{X}}(x) = {e^{-|x|} \over 2}$

I am supposed to calculate the variance and standard deviation of this distribution. My book gives the definition of a variance as follows:

$V(\mathbb{X}) = E(\mathbb{X}^2) - E(\mathbb{X})^2$

To make things easy for myself, I start by calculating $E(\mathbb{X})^2$. Using the definition of the expected value I get

$E(\mathbb{X}) = \int_{-\infty}^{\infty}x*f_{\mathbb{X}}(x)dx = \int_{-\infty}^{\infty}x{e^{-|x|} \over 2}dx$

I start performing the integration and pretty soon realize that this will become $0$, which [WolframAlpha][1] confirms. I then move on to calculating $E(\mathbb{X}^2)$. According to my book, this is

$E(\mathbb{X}^2) = \int_{-\infty}^{\infty}x^2*f_{\mathbb{X}}(x)dx = \int_{-\infty}^{\infty}x^2{e^{-|x|} \over 2}dx$

When integrating this I get that $E(\mathbb{X}^2) = 2$, thusly I get

$V(\mathbb{X}) = E(\mathbb{X}^2) - E(\mathbb{X})^2 = 2-0 = 2$

Satisfied with my aswer, I conclude that if $V(\mathbb{X})=2$ then $\sigma = \sqrt{2}$. I go ahead to check my answers with the book, which states that both the variance and the standard deviation are equal to $1$.

I can clearly see that if one value is one, then so is the other. What I can't see, though, is how the variance becomes one. Could someone please explain?

Comment: The variance is indeed $2$. So there is a mistake in the book answer, and your calculation was presumably correctly done.

Comment: To be more precise, the variance for a Laplace distribution is $2b^2$, where $b>0$ is the scale parameter. For your "standard" case, $b=1$.

Comment: Thank you both, I really appreciate it!